# comparing two regression coefficients obtained by same elastic net regression model

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, regularization, elastic-net

I have 10 responses and 20 predictors for which I measured values in two conditions.
I ran elastic model for each response at each condition separately.
As a result, I will have two association networks between responses and predictors, each for one condition.
I then need to statistically compare the two association networks (edges are weighted based on the regression coefficients obtained by elastic net regression between a predictor and a response).
I need to know whether the association between a response A and a regressor B in condition 1 is significantly different from the association between A and B in condition 2.
Could you maybe help me which kind of test I can use?
Thanks!

Comment: So the predictors were measured at two time points , but the response remained the same?

Comment: Not really! the predictors and responses measured at the same time points, but in two different conditions, in control and in salt.

Comment: so overall you recorded 20. 10 in control and 10 in salt

Comment: actually 20 predictors were measured at 10 time points in condition one, and the same 20 predictors were measured at 10 times points in condition two.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the response in the control group are independent of the one in the experimental group you could try to fit just a single model. And you include control/experimental as a variable and include the interaction with the 20 predictors and the newly added variable. Significant interaction would mean difference in effect of the predictor between the groups.

Comment: This looks like a good approach, but it begs the question of testing significance of coefficients in an Elastic Net model: do you have any ideas how to do that effectively?

Comment: I believe the same as whuber. and the responses are the same variable, but just measured in two different conditions.